# Combinations over a Multiindex DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, combinations, python-itertools, multi-index

I'm trying to make all combinations over a dataframe with a multiindex (Line & Scenario). The dataframe has the following structure and might look like this

| Line | Scenario | Scenario Probability | Periods... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Line 1 | 0 | 0.4 | ... |
| Line 1 | 1 | 0.4 | ... |
| Line 1 | 2 | 0.2 | ... |
| Line 2 | 0 | 0.33 | ... |
| Line 2 | 1 | 0.66 | ... |
| Line 3 | 0 | 1 | ... |
| Line 4 | 0 | 0.1 | ... |
| Line 4 | 1 | 0.3 | ... |
| Line 4 | 2 | 0.5 | ... |
| Line 4 | 3 | 0.05 | ... |
| Line 4 | 4 | 0.05 | ... |

Each line can be seen as a kind of random variable with different characteristics, which are given by the scenarios.
I would now like to form all possible combinations of lines. Each line must occur exactly once in the combination. For example, in the example given, possible combinations would be the following:

```
Line 1 (0), Line 2 (0), Line 3 (0), Line 4 (0) or
Line 1 (0), Line 2 (0), Line 3 (0), Line 4 (1) or
Line 1 (1), Line 2 (1), Line 3 (0), Line 3 (3) and so on
```

I hope you get what kind of combinations I'm looking for. The order doesn't make any difference, I need only to ensure, that every line is in every combination. The variation comes with the scenarios. You don't need to care with the rest of the dataframe. At this point it will have no usage.

I have already the following code:

```
available_lines = df_site.index.tolist()
    
line_combinations = []
all_combinations = itertools.combinations(available_lines, len(df_site.index.levels[0].unique()))
    
for combination in all_combinations:
    if combination[0] not in [c[0] for c in line_combinations]:
        line_combinations.append(combination)
    
print("Line Combinations:")
for combination in line_combinations:
    print(combination)
```

df_site is the name of the dataframe I'm looking at.

Its not working very well, e.g. for the dataframe with Line 1 & 2 with 3 Scenarios each i got the following combinations:

```
`(('Line 1', 0), ('Line 2', 0))
(('Line 2', 0), ('Line 1', 1))
(('Line 1', 1), ('Line 2', 1))
(('Line 2', 1), ('Line 1', 2))
(('Line 1', 2), ('Line 2', 2))`
```

As you may see, not every combination is included. I'm not very sure, what I'm doing wrong. If there might exist a more efficient way, I'm happy for any suggestions. Thank you very much for your help!